# How often is my python program in CGI-BIN called?

Tags: python, cgi

I copied a python file on my CGI-BIN folder, and expect it to run when I browse to the webserver. The python program is structured with a few function definitions (def...), and at the end the main function. So far, so good.

At the end of the main() function, I left an infinite while loop because I wanted to let the main() function called cyclically.

This works, but I observed however, that my main() program is called cyclically anyway. So my endless loop and another -kind of hidden- loop cross each other.

Is an executable python file on cgi-bin always called cyclically. And if so, what is the calling frequency? Can you control this?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "called cyclically". If you have an infinite while loop, your function will never complete.

Comment: That's the point, indeed, the function remains running, but it looks like another instance of the function starts additionally, and a second, a third, and so on. In my browser the data grows and I can carry on scrolling down, the page increases always. When I remove the loop, this behaviour stops, and my page is refreshed every 5 seconds more or less. So I was thinking: what software part is deciding to refresh my page every 5 second, and re-run my function?

Comment: If your browser is refreshing repeatedly, then it's the browser that is calling the function repeatedly.

Comment: Possibly. I am a newbie in CGI. To be more concrete with my question, I tried in the tutorial of http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lab2q/lesson_7/  example 7.1, and changed some things in it. I probably first need to understand what FieldStorage() does.

Comment: Note that that code a) has several indentation errors, which is probably the cause of your recursion, and b) is from a site that's not been updated in 15 years. You should not be using CGI these days unless you have a really good reason. Use a proper Python web framework.

Comment: Thanks! There was indeed a code error. Besides, for another project, I use django, but there I have a nice recent computer available. I tried to explore CGI because I thought this would be more suitable in a very small embedded device. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. That might be the "really good reason". Although it's at least plausible that the overhead of starting up a new interpreter for every page request, as CGI does, could be more expensive on such a device than keeping a long-lasting lightweight WSGI process running. It'd be worth profiling.